# How to get Image Name used in an UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimage

I am using an UIImage, in which I have an Image, and I want to know the name of image.

Comment: i dont think it is possible to get the name of image

Comment: Answer: UIImageView - How to get the file name of the image assigned? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16885708/2316831?stw=2

Comment: See this answer in a related question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72542728/1356407

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That functionality is not built-in to `UIImage` because images are not always loaded from files. However, you could create a custom `UIImageView` subclass to fit your needs.

Comment: @JayD: Not directly from an instance of `UIImage`.

Comment: Wrong, @junaidsidhu has nailed it corretly

Comment: No, this is the correct answer I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72542728/897465

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible. UIImage instance contains the actual image data without any reference to the filename.

Answer (score 3):

this code will help you out

```
    NSString *imgName = [self.imgView1st image].accessibilityIdentifier;

    NSLog(@"%@",imgName);

    [self.imgView2nd setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName]];
```

Comment: this doesn't work because you have to set the accesibiliyIdentifier when assining image

Comment: This is definitely the right answer! People should upvote it. When loading images via local bundle, using XCAssets, the runtime itself will automatically assign the `accessibilityIdentifier` to be the same as the asset name. When loading images dynamically or creating it dynamically, of course there is no built-in solution

Comment: The `accessibilityIdentifier` is exposed only when accessibility is enabled on the device. This might be the case that it works for you in development on the simulator, but won't work on actual user's device.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Neither with simulator or real device. Maybe this requires a specific config / device settings and in this case this answer isn't valid because it is inconsistent and probably not what OP was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Images do not necessarily come from files or other named sources, so not all images even have a name. When you create an image from a file, you could store the name in a separate `NSString*`, and then refer to that stored name when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72542728/897465) has (what I believe) the best answer:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "something")
img?.imageAsset?.value(forKey: "assetName")
```

Here's a handy extension for it:

```
extension UIImage {

    var containingBundle: Bundle? {
        imageAsset?.value(forKey: "containingBundle") as? Bundle
    }

    var assetName: String? {
        imageAsset?.value(forKey: "assetName") as? String
    }

}
```

Comment: Asset name as retrieved is a long string eg 2B21CCA7-DE92-4A8C-A877-E17F96F3368E, not the image name as shown in info eg IMG_4304

Answer (score 0):

On later iOS versions it's possible to extract image name from the  description. Aware, for the debug use only!

```
extension UIImage {

    /// Extracts image name from a description.
    /// * Example description: `<UIImage:0x60000278ce10 named(main: ic_timeline_milestone_bluedot) {16, 16}>`
    /// * Example name: `ic_timeline_milestone_bluedot`
    /// - warning: For the debug use only.
    var name: String? {
        let description = self.description
        guard let regexp = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\(main: (.*)\\)", options: []) else { return nil }
        guard let match = regexp.matches(in: description, options: [], range: description.fullRange).first else { return nil }
        guard match.numberOfRanges > 0 else { return nil }
        let idx1 = description.index(description.startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let idx2 = description.index(description.startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)
        return String(description[idx1..<idx2])
    }
}
```