# Inspecting the string created by stringWithFormat:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

When setting the image for a button, I use `stringWithFormat:` like so:

```
 [buttonImage setImage:[ImgUtil image:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage_%d.png", selectNum + 1 ]] ];
```

I want to inspect that string. I thought maybe I could get the name back from the button:

```
 if (buttonImage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage_2.png"]) {
        NSLog(@"the name of the buttonImage is %@", buttonImage.image);
 }
```

but that doesn't work. How can I look at that string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Image Name used in an UIImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279314/how-to-get-image-name-used-in-an-uiimage) which I answered

Comment: @EvanMulawski: I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes, it is. He wants to get the name of the image represented by the `UIImage` object.

Comment: @EvanMulawski: The question may be the same, but the purpose and the setting is different.

Comment: @nhahtdh: The question title is the same, the question itself is the same, and the end result is the same. Therefore, it is the same question.

Comment: I've edited this post pretty heavily because, based on the accepted answer, and the comment below it, it was completely misleading. Turns out it wasn't a dupe, @Evan, although I agreed with you until I saw the OP's comment.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau: Wow, the OP's entire original question was misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to "test what the "myImage_%d.png" ends up being" in the following line:

```
[buttonImage setImage:[ImgUtil image:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage_%d.png", selectNum + 1 ]] ];
```

Then I would suggest that you reformat and simplify your code.  It will give you the additional advantage of making it easier to read:

```
NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage_%d.png", selectNum + 1 ];
NSLog(@"imageName is %@", imageName);

[buttonImage setImage:[ImgUtil image:imageName]];
```

Comment: that was what I was looking for. worked great. thanks for your help!

Comment: @hanumanDev: All you wanted was the value of that string?! This question is completely misleading. `UIImage` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use associated references to attach a string the key "name" at load time.  You create the UIImage from a file, and attach the name using the objective-c associated references API: [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html)

You can also sub-class UIImage to store an extra name.

You can even add a category to provide an easy API.

Comment: I think associated reference may be a good solution. I don't like sub-classing for such a trivial task, though.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

`buttonImage.image` is a UIImage stored in memory inside the button.

`[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage_2.png"]` creates an entirely different UIImage.  Both UIImages could very well have been created from the same file--in this case, `@"myImage_2.png"`--but they are two separate UIImages in memory.

The `==` check in your line:

```
if(buttonImage.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage_2.png"])
```

Does not check if the UIImages were created from the same file; it checks if they are pointing to the same location in memory.  Which they are not, because they are two separately created and stored UIImage instances.

--

So, no--you cannot do this.  Something that might solve your problem another way, though, is to subclass UIButton and add a properly `NSString* imageFilename`.  (If you're setting different images for each control state, you'd need more than one variable to store those image file names in).  Then override the `setImage:forControlState` method of the UIButton subclass and store the filename there every time the image is changed.  Then you can perform the following check:

```
if([imageFileName isEqualToString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImage_%d.png", selectNum + 1 ]])
```

And that would get you the answer you want!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the UIImage as instance of the class, and compare it. You won't be using more memory than a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

selectNum stands for the selected image, right?If so, try to get selectNum when picking the picture.