# How to access "name" of UIImageView in .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

When i declare an image like this: `IBOutlet UIImageView *circle` in my ViewController.h

How can I then access the "name" **circle** in my ViewController.m file?

I need this "name" to determine which image i want to show.

```
UIImageView *selected = (UIImageView *)[touch view];
selected.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"   circle goes here   "];
```

Code examples are really appreciated :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Folks, this is NOT a duplicate of questions asking about the FILENAME of an image. The poster wants to find the name of the instance variable of the IBOutlet that points to the image view. For that you need to use the objective C runtime write some introspection code. Please vote to re-open the question so I can provide an actual answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *myImage  = [[UIImage alloc] init];

NSString *strProp = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(myImage));

NSLog(@"%@", strProp);
```

**Output:**

```
myImage
```

Comment: I don't want to have an if statement for every picture. I search for a more dynamic solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than searching for the property named `circle`, dynamically, I would recommend you to set a unique `tag` properly to `circle` imageview you have, in your viewDidLoad method or from interface builder, whatever is suitable:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //.........
    circle.tag = 999; //or any other value that lets you determine it uniquely 
    //.........
}
```

And then anywhere in your code, you can determine whether a view is `circle` uiimageview by just verifying its `tag` property like this:

```
UIImageView *selected = (UIImageView *)[touch view];
if(selected.tag == 999) {
    selected.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"   circle goes here   "]; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Ayan, thanks for your answer. What is the reason that you don't recommend to get this property name(circle) dynamically? Is it not possible or?

Comment: For determining a property dynamically from a class, actually you need to use a process called "introspection". For that you need to use "runtime.h" header in your code and introspect a class at runtime by `class_getProperty` function to determine a property, if exists. However that's a hell lot of an overhead to the runtime and i don't recommend it as such to perform a simple task as you were trying.

Answer (score -1):

From the [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279314/how-to-get-image-name-used-in-an-uiimage):

> That functionality is not built-in to `UIImage` because images are not
>   always loaded from files. However, you could create a custom
>   `UIImageView` subclass to fit your needs.

Comment: You should flag or closevote this as a duplicate instead. Right now your post doesn't contain any additional value compared to the original one.