# How to get the custom image name in a UIBarButtonItem button in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have this method in a custom class:

```
func changeImage(btn:UIBarButtonItem, imageName: String){
    btn.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}
```

I would like write another method that can give me the same name passed in the 'imageName' parameter...something like:

```
func getImageName(btn:UIBarButtonItem) -> String{
    return btn.image.someVarOrMethodWithImageName
}
```

I try some of properties and subProperties like

```
    btn.image?.accessibilityIdentifier
    btn.image?.imageAsset.debugDescription
    btn.image?.imageAsset?.value(forKey: "named")
```

And others, but none of them are working.

Lot of thanks!

Comment: We do not have any possibility to directly access the imageName from UIImage/UIImageView. We could store it somewhere/get some reference.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279314/how-to-get-image-name-used-in-an-uiimage

Comment: Is not dup, because this case is for Swift, and that case is for Obj-c :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you can do is subclass `UIBarButtonItem` and declare a property as `var imageName: String?` and when you assign the `image` to your `UIBarButtonItem`, assign this `imageName` with actual value. So that you can access it later anywhere(unless it is your custom 'UIBarButtonItem' class).

For example:

```
class MyBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
    var imageName: String?
}

//....
func changeImage(btn: MyBarButtonItem, imageName: String){
    btn.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    btn.imageName = imageName
}

func getImageName(btn: MyBarButtonItem) -> String? {
    return btn.imageName
}
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh. Is a little frustrating to know that I can't take that property in a more clean way, but thank you so much :)